# ui sortable ungular doesn't work on single-page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

i have project where i use single-page.....i have connected ui angular lib by next steps:

i added scripts

```
<script src=.....jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src=.....jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src=".....1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src=.....sortable.js"></script>
```

than in  module I added :

```
var app = angular.module('abilitonDashboard', ['ngRoute', 'ngLoadScript','ui.sortable']);
```

and on parrent conteiner added attribute ui-sortable="sortableOptions"
for example in table:

```
 <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
       <tr>
           <td> 1 </td>
           <td> 1 </td>
           <td> 1 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td> 2 </td>
           <td> 2 </td>
           <td> 2 </td>
       </tr>  
       <tr>
           <td> 3 </td>
           <td> 3 </td>
           <td> 3 </td>
       </tr>  
       </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="MainApp">

    <head></head>

    <body>

        <table>
            <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
               <tr>
                   <td> 1 </td>
                   <td> 1 </td>
                   <td> 1 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td> 2 </td>
                   <td> 2 </td>
                   <td> 2 </td>
               </tr>  
               <tr>
                   <td> 3 </td>
                   <td> 3 </td>
                   <td> 3 </td>
               </tr>  
            </tbody>    
        </table>

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="sortable.js"></script>

        <script>
            angular.module('MainApp', ['ui.sortable'])
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```